# small APEX trigger for double accounting - efficiency

Tags: apex, trigger

Hi and Happy New year,

In accounting (at least double accounting), a financial move is always between 2 accounts, with one account being debited and the other account being credited.

I've wrote a small Apex trigger that is doing that.

```
trigger AccountingMoveLoading2 on Shipment__c (after update) {

    List<Accounting_Move__c> listaccountingmove = new List<Accounting_Move__c>();

    for (Shipment__c oshipment : trigger.New) {
        if (oshipment.Shipment_Completed__c == True) {
            Accounting_Move__c oAccounting_Move = new Accounting_Move__c();
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Date__c = oShipment.ETD__c;
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Description__c = oShipment.Invoice_Name__c;
            oAccounting_Move.From_Account__c = oShipment.Shipment_Account__c;
            oAccounting_Move.Transaction_Amount_Cred__c = oShipment.CIF_Value__c;
         listaccountingmove.add(oAccounting_Move);
         }
     }
     insert listaccountingmove;


    List<Accounting_Move__c> listaccountingmove2 = new List<Accounting_Move__c>();

    for (Shipment__c oshipment : trigger.New) {
        if (oshipment.Shipment_Completed__c == True) {
            Accounting_Move__c oAccounting_Move = new Accounting_Move__c();
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Date__c = oShipment.ETD__c;
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Description__c = oShipment.Invoice_Name__c;
            oAccounting_Move.From_Account__c = oShipment.Exporter_Account__c;
            oAccounting_Move.Transaction_Amount_Deb__c = oShipment.CIF_Value__c;
         listaccountingmove2.add(oAccounting_Move);
         }
     }
     insert listaccountingmove2;
}
```

It works and does do the job, but is seems a bit cumbersome.
Any suggestion on how to make it more elegant?  or efficient?
Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you want your credit value to be -ve? (being pedantic, if they're accounting entries wouldn't you want equal/opposite amounts to net to 0.00?)

Comment: You are absolutely right! Actually very important and basic, not pedantic at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplification of the trigger is one possibility:

```
   List<Accounting_Move__c> listaccountingmove = new List<Accounting_Move__c>();

    for (Shipment__c oshipment : trigger.New) {
        if (oshipment.Shipment_Completed__c) {

            Accounting_Move__c oAccounting_Move = new Accounting_Move__c(
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Date__c = oShipment.ETD__c,
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Description__c = oShipment.Invoice_Name__c);

            Accounting_Move__c oAccounting_Move2  =  oAccounting_Move.clone();

            oAccounting_Move.From_Account__c = oShipment.Shipment_Account__c;
            oAccounting_Move.Transaction_Amount_Cred__c = oShipment.CIF_Value__c;
            listaccountingmove.add(oAccounting_Move);

            oAccounting_Move2.From_Account__c = oShipment.Exporter_Account__c;
            oAccounting_Move2.Transaction_Amount_Deb__c  = - oShipment.CIF_Value__c; 
            listaccountingmove.add(oAccounting_Move2);
         }
     }

     insert listaccountingmove;
```

Alternatively, consider a workflow rule for the contra

Comment: Slight bug in your answer, From_Account__c should be different for dr/cr line :)

Comment: Thanks for that (blush) - what would be the point of posting zero to ever account :)

Comment: :D you never know with accountants...they do the strangest of things

Comment: What about my edit @max ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Franky. Nice work. I think @"Phil Hawthorn" had a single field in mind. In other words, combine 'Transaction_Amount_Cred__c' and 
 'Transaction_Amount_Deb__c' into a single field ( say 'Transaction_Amount__c' ) if you wish to denote a credit amount as a  negative and  a debit amount as a positive. That way you can verify your transactions lines always net to zero with a simple  rollup summary (or similar)

Comment: Also the approach of a single field for amount could be applied to account. So using your example, 'From_Account__c' could simply be renamed to 'Account__c'

Comment: OK I get it.  Actually I've changed it your way on my trigger.  It makes things even easier to calculate an account balance with roll up summaries.  Thanks again for your advice and good tip.  I didn't know the .clone() things.  Very helpful!

Comment: Actually, @Franky's edit is just as I meant it, there are good reasons why you'd want to maintain two separate fields for dr/cr...consider a 3 line document say with tax you'd want a dr 'total' line with a detail and tax line as cr's (equalling the value of the dr line) which is where the 'Transaction_Amount__c' concept would fall down unless you had some other indicator on the line. Again, I'm being a pedant...been working on accounting systems too long :)

Answer (score 8):

Uses SObject constructor initialization for optimization, as well as combining both actions into a single loop, removed redundant `== true`.

```
trigger AccountingMoveLoading2 on Shipment__c (after update) {
    Accounting_Move__c[] moves = new Accounting_Move__c[0];

    for(Shipment__c record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Shipment_Completed__c) {
            Accounting_Move__c f = new Accounting_Move__c(
                    Accounting_Move_Date__c = record.ETD__c,
                    Accounting_Move_Description__c = record.Invoice_Name__c,
                    From_Account__c = record.Shipment_Account__c,
                    Transaction_Amount_Cred__c = record.CIF_Value__c),
                t = new Accounting_Move__c(
                    Accounting_Move_Date__c = record.ETD__c,
                    Accounting_Move_Description__c = record.Invoice_Name__c,
                    From_Account__c = record.Exporter_Account__c,
                    Transaction_Amount_Deb__c = record.CIF_Value__c
                );
            moves.addAll(new Accounting_Move__c[] { f, t });
        }
    }
    insert moves;
}
```

Comment: insert moves should be outside the for loop?

Comment: You're right. That was a typo.